# Why doesn't jquery seem to be applying vendor-specific css properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I am using jQuery 1.6.1

My problem is that I am attempting to create a DOM element and apply styles to it by passing an object containing the style information to the css() function. It works fine except for the css property '-webkit-overflow-scrolling' which I want to use for native scrolling on iOS devices. Here's what the code looks like.

```
var windowStyles = {
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': 0,
        'right': 0,
        'bottom': 0,
        'left': 0,
        'width': '70%',
        'height': '80%',
        'margin': 'auto',
        'background-color': '#FFFFFF',
        'border': '6px solid #CCCCCC',
        '-webkit-overflow-scrolling': 'touch'
}

var $modalWindow = $('<div>').addClass('modal-window').css(windowStyles);

$('body').append($modalWindow);
```

This mostly works completely fine. The new div is created with all of the listed styles and added to the DOM, but the '-webkit-overflow-scrolling' property is not there. Is it just not possible to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles you see in say the Chrome F12 debug tools include the ones in the DOM and **any extra ones in the CSS file**.

It appears the browser will not store *unknown styles* on elements.
e..g. you cannot set `$element.css("Blah", "Blah")`. Nothing will be added.

If you view DOM settings in the appropriate browser, you will probably see them appear.

Comment: I meant like the Chrome inspector, on whatever browser you are using. I take it from your comment you are using an iPad or similar to view the page? What browser are you using on it?